# How to stop infinite loops using pynput and pyautogui?

Tags: python, onclick, click, pyautogui, pynput

I was trying to emulate "double-clicking" often used in gaming mouses as a python programme but after making a short programme and reading the docs, I realized I caused an infinite loop of clicking!

Now, I would like to continue but I don't know what the best way out of the infinite loop.

My Code:

```
import pyautogui
import random
from pynput import mouse



def on_click(x, y, button, pressed):
    pyautogui.click()
    x = random.randint(1, 2)
    if x == 2:
        pyautogui.click()


# Collect events until released
with mouse.Listener(
        on_click=on_click) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

Thanks!